# How to get the old value in a select without unchecked with option formed with an foreach

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9

I need a little help..

In case of validation errors, when the page is reloaded I lose the information entered previously.

This is my code:

**Controller:**

```
public function create()
    {
        $nationalities = array('Italian','Brazilian','Spanish','Romanian');
        return view('guest.create', ['nationalities'=>$nationalities);
    }


public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'nationality' => 'required'
        ]);

        Guest::create([
            'nationality' => $request->nationality
        ]);

        return redirect(route('guest.index'));
    }
```

**View:**

```
 <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="nationality" class="form-label fw-bold">Select<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <select class="form-select" id="nationality" name="nationality" aria-label="Floating label select example">
        @foreach($nationalities as $nationality)
        <option value="{{$nationality}}">{{$nationality}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

How can I modify the code so that this doesn't happen?

Comment: What error? you need to add more info...

Comment: You are validating nothing, the method you are sharing it is literally just showing the view, did you mean `store` instead of `create`?

Comment: It's not the validation error I need to show. Maybe you didn't read well, I want to return the old value of my select without losing it in case a validation error appears. Now I hope I was clearer.

Comment: I need to see how you are validating... I have 6+ years of experience with Laravel, if I ask for something, please show that info... I am asking because if you are using a `FormRequest` (if you know what that is), then it should be working, if it is a manual validation, then I could try seeing the data...

Answer (score 0):

How can you select back what failed if you did not even ask for the old value?

This may or not work depending on how you are validating, but you did not want to show that...

```html
<div class="mb-3">
    <label for="nationality" class="form-label fw-bold">Select<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <select class="form-select" id="nationality" name="nationality" aria-label="Floating label select example">
        @foreach($nationalities as $nationality)
            <option value="{{$nationality}}" {{ old('nationality') === $nationality) ? 'selected="selected"' : '' }}>{{$nationality}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Updated answer; however it doesn't work like you told me

Comment: write another `<p>` tag anywhere and put `{{ old('nationality') }}`, then send the form again, and when it refreshes, see if it has data, if it is printing something

Comment: tried but it doesn't work

Comment: I am getting very frustrated with you... what does `tried but it doesn't work` mean? I did ask, WHAT ARE YOU GETTING BACK? it is not "going to work or not".... god...

Comment: I get nothing, if I get any error I would write it

Comment: Try using `dd(old('nationality'))`...

Comment: I get `null` ...

Answer (score -1):

```
<option value="{{$nationality}}" @selected(old('nationality')==$nationality)>
 {{$nationality}}
</option>
```

add the `@selected` directive in blade.

Comment: tried but it doesn't work

Comment: put this somewhere in view file. `{{print_r($errors->all())}}` then don't select any options so that validation fails and let redirect to the same page. Check if it is an empty array or has some elements in it.